# Is Time machine able to restore my Windows Partition?

Tags: windows, time-machine, partition

I have 2 partitions on my computer. One with mac os x, another for Windows XP. I want to replace the disk with another one and I  wanted to know if Time  Machine will be able to restore the Windows partition too?

Answer (score 1):

Winclone 3 is the best way to backup/restore a Windows Boot Camp partition. I have used it numerous times to restore such a partition.

http://twocanoes.com/software.php?software=1

Answer (score 0):

No Time Machine does not restore whole partitions: it backs up files and directories on mounted drives and restores files and directories.

**Untested**

You can create an image of the Windows partition with DiskUtility, backup the image (copy it on a different disk) and restore it later.

Comment: I though that Disk Utility has some limitation about Windows format... but maybe these limitations are only about "fixing" and "repairing" problems, but can clone it without problem?

Comment: As far as I know it should be able to create the image but I would test the whole process with an external disk or USB key (create a FAT or NTFS partition, create the image, format and restore) to be sure it works. No guarantees.